# Installing ruby-2.0.0-p0 with rbenv BUILD FAILED

Tags: ruby, installation, rbenv

So I tried to install ruby through rbenv on my new ubuntu 12.04LTS running on VirtualBox.

I got rbenv from https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv and ruby-build from https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.

and then i run the following but build fails :(

```
rbenv install 2.0.0-p0
Downloading ruby-2.0.0-p0.tar.gz...
-> http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p0.tar.gz
Installing ruby-2.0.0-p0...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20130506102349.2564
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20130506102349.2564.log

Last 10 log lines:
installing default gems:      /home/shivin/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0     (build_info, cache, doc, gems, specifications)
                          bigdecimal 1.2.0
                          io-console 0.4.2
                          json 1.7.7
                          minitest 4.3.2
                          psych 2.0.0
                          rake 0.9.6
                          rdoc 4.0.0
                          test-unit 2.0.0.0
The Ruby openssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
```

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need any more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are going to need `libssl-dev`.  For best results install all of the [requirements](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/scripts/functions/requirements/ubuntu#L85) which rvm autolibs function will install for you.  Some of them (like `sqlite3`) presume that you will ultimately be wanting to install Rails, but aren't harmful if you don't need them.

Comment: i didn't use rvm to install on ubuntu. i used rbenv. i did try to install openssl but no luck. Do you happen to know what the line "Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20130506102349.2564" would suggest? Was there a problem with the ruby-build segment of the installation?

Comment: It goes on to show you the last 10 lines of that file, and indicate that openssl is not compiled, and suggests that you will need to install the openssl library.  While RVM does a better job of installing prerequisites for you on Ubuntu, you don't have to use RVM.  Just make use of the instructions.  In a separate comment, I'll show you the command you should use.

Comment: sudo apt-get install g++ gcc make libc6-dev patch openssl ca-certificates libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev autoconf libc6-dev libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison pkg-config libffi-dev

Comment: This worked for me installing 2.0.0-p247 via rbenv on a virgin Raring (Ubuntu 13.04) system: sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

Comment: @moschops your solution worked for me on a fresh/updated mint 15 install.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you need the openssl extension as a prerequisite :

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

should to the trick. Relaunch your RBENV install afterwards.

Comment: i did the above but it gave me the same error. When I install the openssl it said i already have the newest version of openssl. is there a way to uninstall rbenv and ruby-build? So that I can install it using RVM? I read on google that you can't have rvm and rbenv installed at the same time.

Comment: It seems a logical answer but most people on [the ruby build thread](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/377) are installing libssl-dev.$ `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` certainly worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same issue.  moschop's suggestion on the thread worked!

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

and then

```
rbenv install 2.0.0-p247
```

You will have to rehash everytime you install a Ruby version or a gem

```
 rbenv rehash
```

Make a Ruby version default:

```
rbenv global 2.0.0-p247
```